# Reasonable arguments for mapply when working with large Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, apply

I wanted to optimize the rather tedious Pandas operations in my program, so I found out that `.apply(...)` could be replaced by `.mapply(...)`. Therefore, I need to initialize `mapply` using `mapply.init(...)`.

```py
import mapply

# ...

mapply.init(
    n_workers=mapply.parallel.sensible_cpu_count(),
    # chunk_size=?,
    # max_chunks_per_worker=?,
    progressbar=True
)

self.patterns_to_tokens = self.patterns_to_tokens[self.patterns_to_tokens["pattern"].mapply(
    lambda pattern: any([isinstance(slot, LexSlot) for slot in pattern])
)]
```

(Note: `LexSlot` is a custom class I wrote; so my program should just check whether there are any `LexSlot` elements in my DataFrame elements.)

How do I decide which values are suitable for my job? Is there a way to estimate good values based on my RAM and CPU count? The parameters `chunk_size` and `max_chunks_per_worker` confuse me particularly. Also, why can't/shouldn't I use all my logical CPUs with `mapply` (the developers write in their documentation that this would throw a warning and I should use only the "sensible" CPU count)?